# Multiplying polynomials with rational coefficients efficiently

Tags: polynomials, reference-request, fourier-transform, convolution, rational-numbers

Given two degree $n$ polynomial $a, b \in \mathcal{P}_n(\mathbb{R})$, i can compute their product efficiently in $O(n\text{log}n)$ time using Fourier transform.

And in my problem setting, I also know both coefficients of $a, b$ are all in $\mathbb{Q}$. When $n$ gets large, using Fourier transform causes a lot of precision issues for me.

On one hand, I can fall back to long multiplication which has complexity $O(n^2)$ and doesn't have a precision problem.

Wondering if there is any more efficient algorithm that achieves the similar task in the $\mathbb{Q}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Maybe [this algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm) can be leveraged. It has order $n^{\log_2 3}$ when used to multiply $n$-digit integers. Presumably it would have similar time complexity for polynomials, if at all applicable.

Comment: If you know the coefficients as fractions of integers, then you could multiply through by the LCD to get integer coefficients. Then you would only need to calculate the Fourier transform to sufficient precision to distinguish between integer values.

Comment: On the other hand, if you don't know fractional representations of the coefficients - only that your are rational, then I would say you are out of luck. Any number stored in a computer is not only rational, but a member of a very small subset of the rationals. So just the information that your coefficients are rational is not useful by itself.

Comment: I am able to find an old paper "A Fast Algorithm For exact convolution of rational sequences by using integer arithmetic only", but not sure it's applicable and having implementations around